# Extract hostname and datetime from text file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-extraction

I'd like to extract hostnames and datetime from a text file using Python. Below is the text and I need to extract the date behind 'notAfter=' and the hostname behind 'UnitId:' into a dictionary where the datetime is attached to the hostname.

```
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/1
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/0
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/2
```

Comment: so you'll have a list of dictionnaries ?

Comment: @Azro what I want to achieve is that the hostname is attached to the datetime in the dictionary. So I can easily bring them up.

Comment: Yes but there can't be ONE dictionnary

Comment: @azro what is the best way to achieve this? I'm still a beginner in Python so apologies for the noobish questions.

Comment: I just answered 2min ago ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty simple regex will do it `notAfter=(.*)\n\s+UnitId: (.*)`

```
import re

content = """- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/1
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/0
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/2"""

results = [{'datetime': dt, 'hostname': host}
           for dt, host in re.findall(r"notAfter=(.*)\n\s+UnitId: (.*)", content)]
print(results)

# [{'datetime': 'Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT', 'hostname': 'octavia/1'}, 
#  {'datetime': 'Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT', 'hostname': 'octavia/0'}, 
#  {'datetime': 'Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT', 'hostname': 'octavia/2'}]
```

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I think a nested dictionary is better to use, would that be possible using your method?

Comment: @sunbey and what would be the outer key ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches:

```
text = """- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/1
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/0
- Stdout: |
    notAfter=Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT
  UnitId: octavia/2"""
  
import re
output = [{'datetime': data[0], 'hostname': data[1]} for data in re.findall(r'.*notAfter=(.*?)\n.*UnitId:\s*(.*?)\n', text)]
print (output)
```

Output:

```
[{'datetime': 'Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT', 'hostname': 'octavia/1'}, {'datetime': 'Jun  2 10:15:03 2031 GMT', 'hostname': 'octavia/0'}]
```